# The arrays returned from pylab.specgram don't seem to add up to the image, could somebody explain what is returned?

Tags: python, audio, matplotlib, fft, spectrogram

I have looked at some documentation including [this](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.specgram) link. I have also found some code floating around the internet that allowed me to use a wav file to generate some pretty cool spectrograms. Here is the code to do so...

```
"""Generate a Spectrogram image for a given WAV audio sample.

A spectrogram, or sonogram, is a visual representation of the spectrum
of frequencies in a sound.  Horizontal axis represents time, Vertical axis
represents frequency, and color represents amplitude.
"""

import os
import wave
import pylab

def graph_spectrogram(wav_file):
    sound_info, frame_rate = get_wav_info(wav_file)
    pylab.figure(num=None, figsize=(19, 12))
    pylab.subplot(111)
    pylab.title('spectrogram of %r' % wav_file)
    (spect, freqs, time, im) = pylab.specgram(sound_info, Fs=frame_rate)
    print "size of freqs", len(freqs)
    #print "freqs",freqs
    print "size of spect", len(spect)
    print "size of spect[0]", len(spect[0])
    print "size of spect[1]", len(spect[1])
    #print "spect",spect
    print "size of time", len(time)
    #print "time",time
    print "im",im
    pylab.savefig('spectrogram.png')


def get_wav_info(wav_file):
    wav = wave.open(wav_file, 'r')
    frames = wav.readframes(-1)
    sound_info = pylab.fromstring(frames, 'Int16')
    frame_rate = wav.getframerate()
    wav.close()
    return sound_info, frame_rate


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wav_file = 'output.wav'
    graph_spectrogram(wav_file)
```

You can see that I have been printing out what specgram returns in a hope to understand it but I am still pretty lost. The size of frequencies is always length 129 but on the image it seems to have much finer resolution on the frequencies axis ranging from 0Hz to 20000Hz. Why am I continually getting a length of 129 for the frequencies array? The time array makes sense because it is changing according to how long my wav file is. The spect array is just a 2-D array that corresponds to freqs and time. Thank you for the help and if somebody sees a way that I could make this code better just let me know. If somebody also has a good explanation of what this code is really doing I would appreciate that help as well. I am very unfamiliar with pylab. Thanks again.

Here is an image that this is outputting. 
[image: Spectrogram of wav file where I am just snapping my fingers.]

Comment: Your spectrogram implementation is probably using a 256 point FFT, so the useful values in the frequency domain ange from 0 (DC) to 128 (Nyquist), hence the length of 129 (the other 127 values are redundant for purely real input data). Bin resolution (assuming Fs = 44.1 kHz) will be 44.1 kHz / 256 = ~172 Hz.

Comment: Okay, this is starting to make more sense to me. Is it possible to make a spectrogram with the returned data? I know it is making one but I am curious as to how good of a representation this data is of the image. I might just sound confused right about now, sorry.

Comment: Sorry - I don't really know anything about Python or matplotlib - I came here because of the [fft] tag - but if this is anything like Matlab's specgram function then you should be able to get the output data without the plot.

Comment: Okay, thank you for your help!